# comparar xml com respostas dos usuários

Tags: php, xml

colegas. Tenho esse código:

```
<gabarito>
   <avaliacao tipo="Prova" codigo="01" segmento="Ensino Médio" serie="Pré-Vestibular" questoes="20">
      <disciplina nome="Matemática">
         <questao numero="1" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>C</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="2" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>D</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="3" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>A</resposta>
         </questao>
      </disciplina>

      <disciplina nome="Física">
         <questao numero="1" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>C</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="2" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>D</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="3" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>A</resposta>
         </questao>
      </disciplina>
   </avaliacao>
</gabarito>
```

Só que os alunos respondem os gabaritos pelo sistema e fica armazenado dessa forma no banco:

> C,D,A,C,A,E,A,B,C,C,B,D,A,C,D,D,B,B,B,A

Gostaria de fazer a comparação das respostas dos alunos com o do gabarito, contabilizar e separar por cada disciplina. Ex.:

> Matemática => 2 acertos; Física => 4 certos;

É possível fazer isso?

Meu código inicial é esse:

```
foreach($xml->avaliacao->disciplina as $disciplina) {
   $res = $disciplina->attributes();
   if($res["nome"]){
       $questoes = count($xml->avaliacao->disciplina->questao);
       echo $questoes;
   }                                         
}
```

Mas nao estou conseguindo progredir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem onde estão as respostas e respostas corretas para que você consiga determinar a quantidade de acertos, mais acredito que isso te ajudará a entender como buscar os dados que deseja no arquivo.

O que você precisa fazer é percorrer as disciplinas e as questões dentro de cada disciplina, veja o exemplo:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('gabarito.xml');
//percorre as disciplinas
foreach($xml->avaliacao->disciplina as $disciplina) {
    // imprime o nome da disciplina
    echo $disciplina->attributes()->nome.'<br>'; 
    //percorre as questões
    foreach ($disciplina as $questao) { 
        echo $questao->attributes()->numero . ':' . $questao->resposta.'<br>';
    }


}
```

Esse código gera a saída abaixo conforme os dados de seu arquivo:

```
Matemática
1:C
2:D
3:A
Física
1:C
2:D
3:A
```

Comment: Abfurlan... funcionou... eu não teria conseguido sem sua ajuda...obrigado